# Is it possible to record Voice Memos on Apple Watch while on an iPhone call?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, microphone, voice-memo

Is it possible to be on a speakerphone call with my iPhone and then use the Voice Memos app on the Apple Watch to record the conversation? I'm not thinking that the Apple Watch would have access to the iPhone's mic or anything sophisticated like that… just record the audio coming from the iPhone's speaker and the audio coming from my mouth.

I tried to launch Voice Memos on my iPhone during a call. Unsurprisingly, the mic was blocked while the call was active. It feels like an Apple*y* thing to also block Voice Memos on the Apple Watch during a call. I don't have an Apple Watch… otherwise I'd be testing this on my own.

And yes, I know there are other methods of recording calls (via apps that intercept calls and other similar services, jailbreaking, and even just getting a pocket recorder thing), but I'm already interested in an Apple Watch, and this functionality would be icing on the cake.

---

The backstory, if you're interested: I'm rearranging some personal finance stuff and much of the phone conversations I have with financial advisors goes right over my head (i.e. rapid-fire jargon, acronyms, and calculations). My hand written notes can't keep up! It would be great if I could just record the call so that I can research terminology and go over the calculations later. Not trying to do anything nefarious here… I would, of course, inform the person on the other line that I would be recording.

Comment: Did you try Voice Memos on your Apple Watch?

Comment: See the bit about not owning an Apple Watch… if I did, of course I would just test myself.

Comment: Whoops! My mistake.

Comment: @MacintoshFan No worries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the loop here, yes, you can record audio on your Apple Watch while your iPhone is on an active call (on speaker phone). I do this all the time to supplement my notes from an important phone call with an audio recording… with the permission of the person on the other line, of course.